# Form's uploaded file disappears on canceling new selection of file

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a simple form on my webpage.

```html
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input id="browse" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Now, my problem is when I browse and choose file to upload it shows which file I am going to upload. 
[image]
But when I click on Choose file and browse again and this time if I change my mind mid way and hit cancel then old selected image also goes away. 
[image]

On canceling it removes already selected image also.

[image]

Why does this happen and what to do if I want my old selected image to be selected after browsing again and canceling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The solution is to watch for the file input changes in JavaScript, when it change if have a file, save it into a variable, if value comes null and the variable have a file saved, inject the file into to the file input throug JavaScript.

Comment: This is built-in behavior and cannot be overridden. Different user agents may behave differently. If you don't like this behavior, you'll have to implement your own GUI for selecting files and pass the selected file to a real `input type='file'` behind the scenes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - you can't set the value of a file input.

Comment: also, on mac/ff the desired behavior is the default behavior.. the only real workarounds involve using ajax to upload the file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Carlos , added this javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById("browse");
var selectedFile;
input.addEventListener('change', updateImageDisplay);
function updateImageDisplay() {
    if(input.files.length==0) {
        input.files = selectedFile;
   }
   else {
       selectedFile = input.files;
   }
}
```

and now it works fine! you can check [here](https://codepen.io/taksuparth/pen/VQYEWO).